# Calling gpg from SAP via external command SM69 - skipped: No public key

Tags: gnupg, pgp, sap-basis

I am able to call gpg installed on the SAP application server and run commands like `--help` successfully. All public keys have been trusted and the encryption works from the command prompt on the Windows server.

However, when I try to encrypt a file from SAP via the transaction code `SM69`, I receive this error:

> skipped: No public key

Comment: Are you running SAP under the same user you managed and verified the keys with? GnuPG has per-user keyrings.

Comment: Ah, this may be the issue, it is a different account. I will create the keys from SAP versus on the application server directly with the network user. However, I am unable to use the command pgp from SAP, I have to specify the path to the pgp executable for any gpg commands to work from SAP.

Comment: You're using `pgp` and `gpg` randomly. You're aware those are different implementations of OpenPGP? The issue might be related, though -- the `%PATH%` variable might be set up differently among the users, so GnuPG might be included for the user you used to setup the keys, but not the one used for SAP.

Comment: Not using pgp, only gpg, may have been a typo. I was not able to create the  public keys for the SAP user due to other tasks but I am trying this now via the external command from within SAP which. This will be done under the SAP server user account. As I mentioned, gpg is installed on the E drive and when on logged into the server the command gpg works fine, from SAP I have to specify the full path to gpg.exe in order to execute commands, so we are looking into the environment variables for this issue.